# How can I get rid of unwanted email addresses?

Tags: firefox, google-accounts

To be more specific, I use Firefox 115.8.0esr (64-bit) on Debian 11, and I sometimes have to authenticate with my email address to use some Google services; for some reason Firefox (or is it Google?) remembers addresses I don't use any more:

[image]

Is there any way to get rid of them? Or are they possibly in a file I can manipulate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page in your screenshot is 100% Google – their login webpage uses cookies stored by Firefox to keep track of accounts you've used in the past, but Firefox is overall completely unaware of the purpose of each cookie that websites may use.

Clearing cookies (and Local Storage) for google.com – e.g. through <kbd>F12</kbd> ⇒ 'Storage', while you have the auth page open – would cause the webpage to forget everything.

If you want to remove individual accounts, [follow Google documentation](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1721977?hl=en):

> ##### Remove your account from the sign-in page
>
> 1. On your device, go to a browser where you're signed in, like Chrome.
> 2. Go to myaccount.google.com.
> 3. In the top right, select your profile picture or initial.
> 4. Select **Sign out** or **Sign out of all accounts**.
> 5. Select **Remove an account**.
> 6. Next to an account, select Remove ❌.

Comment: THat seems to have done it - thanks!